# I need .mat files as my pc doesn't have enough RAM to run the commands

Tags: matlab

Can somebody please create 2 .mat files for me?
Relatively simply:

1. M12= nchoosek(1:45,12);
2. M14 = nchoosek(1:45,14);

I need the matrices M12 and M14.

My pc doesn't have enough RAM to run them.

Thank You

Comment: 1. We don't do homework. 2. We don't share files. 3. If you can't use those mat files, why you need them ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a request for direct assistance on a project.

Answer (score 4):

You need `nchoosek(45,12)*12*4/1024/1024/1024` = 1.285 TB of RAM to keep the matrix. So you should consider a non-brute force solution instead.